# auth/network-request-failed Firebase ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a ReactJS app with a firebase(3.3.0) login.

I'm trying to connect to Firebase Auth, but I get rejected. Something is blocking my connection. I don't know if it's in the client side. It's strange that I can view information from my Firebase Database and I can display information on my website. I tried the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method in pure JavaScript and it works well. I don't know if this is a problem with ReactJS.

```js
function toggleSignIn() {
  if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
    // [START signout]
    firebase.auth().signOut();
    // [END signout]
  } else {
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    if (email.length < 4) {
      alert('Please enter an email address.');
      return;
    }
    if (password.length < 4) {
      alert('Please enter a password.');
      return;
    }
    // Sign in with email and pass.
    // [START authwithemail]
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // [START_EXCLUDE]
      if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
        alert('Wrong password.');
      } else {
        alert(errorMessage);
      }
      console.log(error);
      //document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').disabled = false;
      // [END_EXCLUDE]
    });
    // [END authwithemail]
  }
}
```

And this is the HTML where I'm using it:

```
<form onSubmit={toggleSignIn}>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block" id="submit">Ingresar</button>
            </div>
            <br/>
</form>
```

Console log error: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.

Thanks!

Comment: yeah then its probably an problem with your internet, even i get this error sometimes but it is temporary.